# Is it possible to register a Domino Server with the Java API or C API?

Tags: java, c, docker, xpages, lotus-domino

We are well on our way to Dockerizing Domino.  In fact, we have a Domino Docker running in IBM Cloud (bluemix) that replicates with on prem.

What we want to be able to do is automate the standing up of a Domino server.

In our script, we are thinking of calling a custom program we can build that will use either the C API or Java API to register a new server, deploy a XPages (JSF) application to it, and start the server, replicate over the common user directory (names.nsf) from the master server.

Currently, we started the Domino Container in CentOS in listener mode.  We registered the server on prem, and copied over a bunch of files (server.id is one of them) and edited confirmation to manually configure it.  We want to automate this process.

Any insights on how this can be better accomplished? any api references you can share to get us most of the way there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. We have done this in Lotusscript using LS2CAPI. 
As we are accesing API functions, this is also possible using Java. Not sure, if domino-jna already includes the needed Api calls, but this can be implemented. Take a look at github for Karsten Lehmann and domino-jna.
domino-jna can be used from XPages as well.

Comment: I can see value to a command line utility that can perform the functions of the Domino Administrator client.